# I lost 1GB of storage in C drive after deleting a veracrypt volume. How can i recover this lost disk space?

Tags: veracrypt

So I created a veracrypt file hosted volume/container and had a hidden volume inside to try it out(totalling 1GB). After a day or two, I permanently deleted the container file (after dismounting it) but i lost the equivalent amount of space from C drive. Is there way to recover this and how to prevent this in a future use of veracrypt volumes?

Comment: This shouldn't happen.

Comment: @davidgo could it be because i did not decrypt it before deleting it.?.  I did the same in D drive with a 500mb Veracrypt volume(but this had no hidden volume) and permanently deleted it and found that there was no loss of disk space like the probelm mentioned here.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to post that comment (and don't know why it showed up). Please ignore it. I realised that its likely you created a disk partition for veracrypt rather then a file partition - and that could be the root of your problem. I also realise I've never used Veracrypt and only used truecrypt (its predecessor) under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Open the folder in VeraCrypt
2. Move or delete the contents
3. Then, and only then, delete the dismounted Folder or File.

I did this just yesterday and it worked fine. No loss of drive space.

**Hint:** never reconfigure VC when you are in a hurry. Plan it all out and troubleshoot before you change anything in VC. Try it out by creating a small dummy crypt, then populate it with generic files. Close and re-mount the crypt. Now, delete the contents (remember generic files only). Now delete the folder from your menu panel. Finally, check your drive capacity. It should show the "plus-up" in size. Always test small, so you fail small and recoverable. Do your last step in any task or job first and you will be rewarded.

Comment: not sure why you are addressing this to me.  I don't have a problem with Veracrypt, and I am expert at handling block and file devices and understanding how this all fits together.   I posit that the OP has not used a folder, rather they have partitioned their disk - if they have indeed done this, then they would need to use block level tools to delete the Veracrypt partition and expand the data partition to recover this space. (David Go - Truecrypt user occassionally way-back when - but for a long time now using LUKS on LVM on RAID on Linux instead!)

Answer (score 0):

I had only recreated a 200GB volume on my 1TB SSD and, like Camio I wanted it to be a smaller volume, so created another 100GB volume and have files transferred over before deleting the 200GB volume container (file).

I thought that was straightforward enough and could get back 200GB of space but apparently my file manager does not reflect the free space recovered.

What do I need to do now?

Comment: Have you looked at uour recycle bin

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169413)